# Ultrapower from $\kappa$-complete $L$-ultrafilter is well-founded (Exercise 18.5, Jech's Set Theory)

Tags: logic, set-theory

Exercise 18.5 of Jech's *Set Theory* says:

> Let us assume that for some uncountable regular cardinal $\kappa$, every constructible $X \subseteq \kappa$ either contains or is disjoint from a closed unbounded set. Then $0^\sharp$ exists.

The hint below says:

> Let $D$ be the collection of all constructible subsets of $\kappa$ containing a closed unbounded subset. $D$ is an $L$-ultrafilter and every intersection of less than $\kappa$ elements of $D$ is non-empty hence the ultrapower $\operatorname{Ult}_D(L)$ is well-founded and gives an elementary embedding of $L$ in $L$.

I believe the hint basically solves the problem, except to check that the ultrapower $\operatorname{Ult}_D(L)$ is well-founded. It is known that (also mentioned in the book, Page 324) if $M$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then $D$ being a $\sigma$-complete $M$-ultrafilter is not sufficient to conclude that $\operatorname{Ult}_D(M)$ is well-founded - the descending sequence need not be in $M$.

I do not know why it is different in the case of $L$. My guess is that it follows from $\operatorname{Ult}_D(L) \subseteq L$, but this would not immediately imply that the descending sequence is in $L$.

Comment: But the club filter on $\kappa$ is $\sigma$-closed. So for any decreasing $\omega$-sequence in $D$, its intersection is non-empty. That's enough to run the proof that the ultrapower is well-founded.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan I don't think that is the club filter of $L$. It may be possible that for some $X \subseteq \kappa$ in $L$, it contains a club in $V$ or is disjoint from a club in $V$, but neither contains a club in $L$ nor is disjoint from a club in $L$.

Comment: I'm talking about the club filter in $V$. $D$ is the intersection of the club filter in $V$ with $L$.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan sure, but $D$ is not closed under arbitrary countable intersections - only if $\{X_n : n < \omega\} \in L$, then can we guarantee that $\bigcap X_n \in D$.

Comment: The standard proof that $\operatorname{Ult}_U(V)$ is well-founded for $\sigma$-complete ultrafilter $U$ is the following: Let $[f_0] \ni^* [f_1] \ni^* \cdots$. Let $X_n := \{\alpha < \kappa : f_n(\alpha) \in f_{n+1}(\alpha)\}$. Then $X := \bigcap X_n \in U$, so for any $\alpha \in X$ we have that $f_0(\alpha) \ni f_1(\alpha) \ni \cdots$, a contradiction. We can't immediately repeat this proof in this case.

Comment: All you need to reach the contradiction is that $X$ is non-empty.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan right, that makes sense. Does that imply that the remark made by Jech is incorrect?

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan oh nevermind, the proof does not go against the remark by Jech. Thank you!